# Atribuir valor utilizando val(valor) ou attr('value', valor) não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o *typeahead*, que funciona da seguinte forma, todo texto que digito no campo ele pega o valor do campo, vai ate uma base de dados, pesquisa e cria um *dropdown* com os valores encontrados.

Ele funciona perfeitamente, mas eu queria que assim que fosse pressionado o botão enter o campo completasse com o primeiro valor do dropdown.

Consigo pegar o primeiro valor com:

```
var valor = $(".tt-suggestion p").first().text();
```

Mas ao tentar setar ele no campo utilizando:

```
$("#cidade_estado").val(valor);
```

ou

```
$("#cidade_estado").val(valor);
```

Não acontece nada.

Eu sei que ele esta entrando no if já que ele faz o:

```
$("#telefone").focus();
```

Normalmente e mostra os valores no console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.cidade_estado').typeahead({
        name: 'municipio',
        remote: 'action/getMunicipios.php?query=%QUERY'
    }).keypress(function (e) {
         var valor = $(".tt-suggestion p").first().text();
         console.log("Aqui: " + valor);
        if (e.which == 13) {
            console.log("13: " + valor);
            $("#cidade_estado").val(valor);
            $('#cidade_estado').attr('value', valor);
            $("#telefone").focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
            <form id="formemail" action="action/enviaemail.php" method="post">
                <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo">
                <input name="empresa" type="text" placeholder="Empresa">
                <input id="cidade_estado" name="cidade_estado" class="cidade_estado" type="text" placeholder="Cidade">
                <input name="telefone" class="grupocontato" id="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone">
                <input name="email" class="grupocontato" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                <input class="btnContato" type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
```

Console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O valor está sendo impresso normalmente no console.log? Você poderia colocar o trecho HTML também?

Comment: O valos é mostrado normalmente no console, eu também tentei colocar uma string qualquer lá e da o mesmo efeito, ou seja nada.

Comment: Ja tentou setando ele mesmo ? $(this).val(valor)

Comment: Não tinha, mas testei aqui agora e não funcionou.

Comment: O que `console.log("13: " + valor);` exibe?

Comment: faz o seguinte teste: `console.log("13: " + valor, $('#cidade_estado').length);`.

Comment: O resultado foi este: "13: São Francisco do Guaporé, RO 1", ou seja ele realmente não esta setando.

Comment: Fiz o seguinte console.log("13: " + valor, $(this).text().length); ele retornou 25, ou seja, ele seta, mas de alguma forma o plugins não mostra ou remove este valor.

Comment: Ah, vc quer preencher o campo do plugin ? precisa triggerar um clique no valor em questão, veja qual a identificação do elemento que  o typeahead renderiza sobre o input, e trigere um clique no valor que você quer em vêz de tentar dar um val(value), acho que assim vai preencher

Comment: @AnthraxisBR se você quiser postar a resposta para eu poder marcar ela como respondida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do **AnthraxisBR** a questão foi resolvido:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".twitter-typeahead span").text('dfsd');
    var campo = $('input.cidade_estado');
    campo.keypress(function (e) {
         var valor = $(".tt-suggestion p").first().text();
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(".tt-suggestion p").trigger( "click" );
            $("#telefone").focus();
            return false;
        }
    }).typeahead({
        name: 'municipio',
        remote: 'action/getMunicipios.php?query=%QUERY'
    });
});
```